# What is wrong with new upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, 20.04

Recently i upgraded to Ubuntu20.04

**Kernel: 5.4.0-26-generic**
This is the error msgs i get at every startup:

```
[ 0.852002 ] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
[ 1.034932 ] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
ln: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory

/dev/sda1: clean, xyz/xyz files, xyz/xyz blocks
```

In update news it was said that Ubuntu20 has better boot times with lz4 but i read this bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660, its similar to what i am facing, should i switch to gzip ? Or any solution ?

Comment: Just updated - I see the same error. Booting stops on this one

Comment: It happens with me sometimes and sometimes it dont, but system always boots for me, even after this msg

Comment: Have same issue too! Also my laptop always performs fsck on boot and sometimes didn't start. I already check the hardware including ssd. I wonder why all times wrong inodes and blocks cound.  In boot log i see `ln: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory
  Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
  Cannot process volume group vgubuntu` . I use lvm with encryption, my swapfile located in root.  `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root contains a file system with errors, check forced.`

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly I change my `fstab` by swaping disk identifiers back to `/dev/****` format:

```
     /dev/sdb2 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
    # swap was on /dev/sdc3 during installation
    # UUID=99e8278d-830c-4edf-8461-4838bd1bccf6 none swap sw 0 0
```

2. Then remove `lvm2` related packages, I don't use any lvm2 partitions.

You can do this via rescue mode. When you inside grub menu choose `advanced options`, enable network (this will remount your filesystem in read/write mode) and select root shell.

Comment: Editing fstab directly is highly inadvisable. Is it possible to accomplish the same steps without editing fstab directly?

Comment: @johnkieran, I don't know, actually, don't know what exactly causes boot to freeze. You can try to remove lvm2 packages first and only then edit fstab.